# How to store post-user information in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a voting option for the posts on my site. I need to be able to store which users voted for which posts. In a standard website, I would just create a userVoteXpost table with columns: userId, postId, vote. In wordpress how do I store this kind of post-user info? Should I create a new piece of post meta every time a user votes for a specific post? Something like:

```
<?php add_post_meta($post_id, $user_id, $vote_value); ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would Wordpress matter when building a voting system?

Comment: Why use metadata - why not just create that custom database table and query it directly through WordPress?

Answer (score -1):

> you going in right path..
> when user give vote to post than insert
>   that 
>   
> user's userID ,
> postID for which user giving vote & 
> vote status, i
>   mean up(1) or down(0)
>
> & whenever user change his vote for specific post then simply update
>   vote status value using that
>  user's userID & postID

Comment: Can you describe how I would go about creating a table, inserting data and querying data from a custom data table in wordpress? I have experience working in SQL Server but am pretty new to wordpress. Thanks.